# What is the major product obtained on acidification of substituted epoxide?

Tags: reaction-mechanism

## The problem

[image]

Source : MS Couhan (problems in organic chemistry . Chapter: Alcohols , phenols and ethers).

## My Thoughts

[image]

If I proceed along $\ce{path 1}$ , $\ce1a$ is formed . It is unstable due to inductive withdrawing effect of $\ce{C=O}$ neighboring to it. Eventually $\ce2$ is obtained.

However, along $\ce{path 2}$ relatively more stable $\ce{3a}$ (compared to $\ce{1a}$) is formed. $\ce3a$ on ring expansion gives $\ce{3b}$ , leading to $\ce{4}$  ($\ce{3b}$ is relatively unstable compared to $\ce{1b}$).

## My question

Which of the two paths should I choose that would lead to a major product ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reaction of epoxyketone **1** affords diketone **2** under photochemical and thermal conditions ostensibly through the diradical.<sup>[1](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo00922a002)</sup> Boron trifluoride provides the diketone **3** through acyl bond migration and not via alkyl group migration as in your intermediate **3a**. I have not located a proton-catalyzed reaction. Unfortunately, diketone **3** was not one of your choices.
[image]

1) [John R. Williams, George M. Sarkisian, James Quigley, Aaron Hasiuk, and Ruth VanderVennen, *J. Org. Chem.*, **1974**, *39*, 1028.](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo00922a002)

Comment: @ user55119 this solves my problem. The intermediate formed after reaction with Boron triflouride is more stable then 3b or 1a.This could be the major product.

Comment: Cation 1a is a bad choice in any event.